# Does benzene sulphonic acids show steric inhibition of resonance / ortho effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, steric-effects

I have read about ortho effects in aniline ([steric inhibition of protonation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho_effect)) and benzoic acids but have not seen anything about Sulphonic Acids ($\ce{-SO3H}$) do they also show considerable ortho effect?